# G++ compiling on Cygwin

Tags: opencv, g++, cygwin, windows-7-x64

I am following Naotoshi Seo [tutorial](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) for OpenCV haartraining. I am trying to compile his script that should merge previously generated *.vec files into one.

My working environment is Windows 7 x64 and Cygwin

When I run the code:

```
$ g++ 'pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv' -I. -o mergevec mergevec.cpp cvboost.cpp cvcommon.cpp cvsamples.cpp cvhaarclassifier.cpp cvhaartraining.cpp
```

I get error:

```
 $ g++: error: pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv: No such file or directory
```

Please note that the file mergevec.cpp has been copied to the directory where I run the code from.

Hope that somebody will be able to help me with my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backticks, not single quotes.

This:

```
g++ 'pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv' -I. -o mergevec \
    mergevec.cpp cvboost.cpp cvcommon.cpp cvsamples.cpp \
    cvhaarclassifier.cpp cvhaartraining.cpp
```

passes `'pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv'` as a literal string argument (without the quotes) to the `g++` command. This:

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -I. -o mergevec \
    mergevec.cpp cvboost.cpp cvcommon.cpp cvsamples.cpp \
    cvhaarclassifier.cpp cvhaartraining.cpp
```

executes the command `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` and passes its *output* as one or more arguments to `g++`, which is what you want. You can also write this as:

```
g++ $(pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv) -I. -o mergevec \
    mergevec.cpp cvboost.cpp cvcommon.cpp cvsamples.cpp \
    cvhaarclassifier.cpp cvhaartraining.cpp
```

if your shell supports it (csh, tcsh, and old versions of sh don't; most other modern shells do).

If the tutorial you're using shows single quotes for that command, you should probably let the author know.